# To build my react native app with the iOS 13 SDK, I upgrade xcode from 10.3 to 11.5, so why my app doesn't work?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

We received, me and my team at work, a message from the App Store Team which contains:

```
Dear Developer,
We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "XXXX" version. 
Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:ITMS-90725: SDK Version Issue - This app update was built with the iOS 12.4 SDK. 
As of June 30, 2020, updates to apps for iPhone or iPad must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later.
ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - App updates that use UIWebView will no longer be accepted as of December 2020.Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability.
```

- So I started by **ITMS-90725** which seems to be the first one we should fix. To build the **react native app** in the **iOS 13 SDK**, i needed to **upgrade the xcode version from 10.3 to 11.5**.
- I did the upgrade thing Then built the app in the iOS 13 SDK, the build succeeded but the app couldn't run and after some debugging stuff i found this problem:

---

```
Thread 1: Exception: "App called -statusBar or -statusBarWindow on UIApplication: this code must be changed as there's no longer a status bar or status bar window.
Use the statusBarManager object on the window scene instead."
```

---

- Then I tried a lot to search about that and until now i can't find any solution according to ***react native***.

> my config after running the command `react-native info` =>

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.5
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Memory: 273.72 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.16.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - ~/.yarn/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.9.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.5, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.6 AI-192.7142.36.36.6200805
    Xcode: 11.5/11E608c - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
    react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5
```

> The dependancies we use =>

```
"dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-native": "^2.1.0",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.3.1",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "1.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "2.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "3.2.1",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^1.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/core": "3.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "3.6.2",
    "appcenter": "^3.0.3",
    "appcenter-analytics": "^3.0.3",
    "appcenter-crashes": "^3.0.3",
    "deepmerge": "^4.0.0",
    "geolib": "^3.0.4",
    "i18n-js": "^3.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-range": "^4.0.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.26",
    "normalize-strings": "^1.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "qs": "^6.9.0",
    "ramda": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-is": "^16.10.1",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-adjust": "4.18.1",
    "react-native-awesome-card-io": "^0.8.2",
    "react-native-calendars": "https://github.com/freework-gmbh/react-native-calendars.git#20dc9a8",
    "react-native-config": "0.11.7",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "0.8.0",
    "react-native-deep-link": "0.2.9",
    "react-native-device-info": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-email-link": "1.4.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-idfa": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-indicators": "0.13.0",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "1.2.1",
    "react-native-joi": "0.0.5",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.9.1",
    "react-native-localize": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-masked-text": "1.13.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "https://github.com/Squirel-SI/react-native-material-dropdown.git",
    "react-native-phone-input": "0.2.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "1.3.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "4.1.2",
    "react-native-screen-brightness": "2.0.0-alpha",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.3",
    "react-native-sensitive-info": "^5.5.3",
    "react-native-webview": "7.4.1",
    "react-navigation": "4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "2.2.2",
    "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "4.0.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "1.9.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "2.5.5",
    "react-redux": "7.0.2",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.1",
    "rn-viewpager": "https://github.com/Squirel-SI/React-Native-ViewPager.git",
    "striptags": "^3.1.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.0",
    "url-join": "^4.0.1"
  },
```

**Can anyone of you help me to fix that ? Please !**

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix the crash above, the problem is related to IOS status Bar functionality.

> Before, using the sdk IOS 10.3, we had this block of code which
> controlled the appearance of status Bar in the **AppDelegate.m**
> project file:

```
[application setStatusBarHidden:NO];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

UIView *statusBar = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"] valueForKey:@"statusBar"];

if ([statusBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)]) {
   statusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:8.0/255.0f green:128.0/255.0f blue:166.0/255.0f alpha:1.0];
}
```

**So by removing those lines, the app works perfectly except for one thing, the status bar loses the color that we want to use for that. I'm still looking for a good solution to control the style of the status bar on the IOS side using the sdk IOS 13.5.**